# Initializing the ESC through microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, brushless-dc-motor, 8051, motor-controller

[image]I have an esc and a brush less dc motor. the connections are given in the pictures. i have written the program for the micrcontroller such that it send 1ms high 19ms low pulses to esc for 5 seconds. then i change the high duration to 2ms and low to 18ms. but nothing happens at the esc not the motor. the motor doesnt rotates. i tried 1.5ms high too, but nothing happens. is there any initialization of esc, so that then pwm is sent to it for rotating the motor. i mean that is there any serial communication involved in it? if yes then what are the instruction?

[image]

Comment: where are the pictures?

Comment: there usually is an initialization. refer to the ESC manual, but to arm it you usually should keep the throttle at 0% for some time.

Comment: I HAVE ADDED THE PICTURES.

Comment: in the esc mannual there is only instructions about the remote controlled programming, and nothing for microcontroller. i want programming from a microcontroller i.e 8051.

Comment: so you are simulating RC style 50Hz signals?

Comment: yes, but how should i do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used 2 ESCs in a hovercraft project I built. Brushless ESCs expect a calibration at power up. Usually this is achieved by sending the high value pulse (2ms) first, waiting for around 2-3 seconds for the beep, then sending the low value (1ms) pulse, and waiting for another beep (another 2-3 seconds). ESC then identifies these are the values you will send for max and zero speed. After that you are free to speed up from zero. Usually, for most ESCs, the low pulse duration doesn't matter as long as it is around 20ms.

Comment: thanks, but have  you performed that and did that worked? what was the combination of wires, please tell me

Comment: Yeah This initialisation process worked for me. No special connections. ESC power to the power rails, and ESC signal line to a PWM pin in the micro-controller.

Comment: its not working still, i did as you said, but nothing cchanged, what now?